# How do I indicate a user's input has ended when writing to a file in Python?

Tags: python

I believe in C we could do ctrl+z for EOF (ctrl+z worked for this), but how do I do this in Python? I'm using `'0'` temporarily. I'm using Windows 10 with Python 3.11.

```
#create a text file and write some lines to it

f = open("newfile.txt",'w')
line = ""
while line != '0': #I'm not sure what to use to indicate the end of the user's input
    line = input()
    f.write(line + '\n')

f.close()
```

Comment: I don't think there's any such thing in python. Ctrl+c will terminate the program but then the file buffer might not be written because `.close()` wouldn't run

Comment: What happens when you do ctrl-z?

Comment: If the user just types Enter, do you want to capture that as valid input?

Comment: On unix, you can type ctrl-D (only at the beginning of a line) to close the input stream.

Comment: Will it break the loop @JohnGordon? I suspect not. I don't use C so I'm not sure exactly the behaviour expected here. Surely in both languages the outer `while` just goes again?

Comment: @John Gordon I want it to read newlines, like if the person was making a document themselves through the shell or a script. But what do I input in the keyboard to indicate input has ended? This is just for testing. Yes Ctrl+D returns EOF, but then f.close() doesn't execute.

Comment: I'm using Windows 10. Question edited. ctrl+z starts erasing lines in the shell after I've entered them, even going up lines.

Comment: Are you running the Python program in a different environment than the C program? Would've expected ctrl-z to have the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

If you do press ctrl+z  for the input you would get an EOFError. So you could change your code as follows,

```
with open('newfile.txt', 'w') as f:
    while True:
    try:
        line = input()
        f.write(line + '\n')
    except EOFError:
        break
```

Comment: They said *"ctrl+z starts erasing lines in the shell after I've entered them, even going up lines."*

Comment: @KellyBundy it did the same for me but only in IDLE, not a console window.  And I still had to hit Enter before it recognized the ^Z.

Comment: @MarkRansom Right, that's how I vaguely remember it for console window as well. So then I guess the OP is using IDLE and this answer should say ctrl-d instead?

Comment: @Ireonus Alternatively, try `for line in sys.stdin:`.

Comment: @KellyBundy I didn't know Ctrl-D worked in IDLE!  That's counter-intuitive on Windows.

Comment: @MarkRansom Did you test it? I currently can't, I just think I remember that.

Comment: @KellyBundy yes I did, because I found it hard to believe.  Python 3.8.6 on Windows.